# call ajax in separate javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new in jquery, ajax but I want to call ajax in separate javascript function because that JSP file is dynamically created and button id in JSP file is also created using for loop.
I sharing my code and is there is a solution for this to pass button id to jquery function and pass that id to ajax calling through Jquery.

Here is code for .js file to call ajax through jquery :

```
function insertData(idvalue)
{
var forsplit = idvalue.id.split("_");
var qtsrl = forsplit[2];
var qtno = forsplit[3];

var queryid=idvalue.id;

var qtsrl_id = document.getElementById("qstn_srl_"+qtsrl+"_"+qtno).value;
var qstn_no_id = document.getElementById("qstn_no_"+qtsrl+"_"+qtno).value;

$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: "aftermarksave.jsp",
    data:{setvalues : qtsrl_id},
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) 
    {
        alert("Data passed");
    },
    error: function(data) 
    {
        alert('Not passed Data: '+qtsrl_id);
    }   
});

}
```

Here I want to pass"qtsrl_id" to "aftermarksave.jsp" through Jquery:Ajax

And here is my dynamically generated .JSP file that "this" is passed to javascript function and extract current id from "this" object

```
fw1.write("<td><lable for='marksimilar'>"+getmarkentry+"</lable>");
                fw1.write("<input type='hidden'    id='markentry_"+getmarkentry+"' value="+getmarkentry+">");
                fw1.write("<br>");
                fw1.write("<label>Serial No</label>");
                fw1.write("<br>");
                fw1.write("<input type='text' size='10' id='qstn_srl_"+queserial+"_"+queno+"' onBlur='makecapital();doOnBlur(this)'>");
                fw1.write("<br>");  
                fw1.write("<label>Question No</label>");
                fw1.write("<br>");
                fw1.write("<input type='text' size='10' id='qstn_no_"+queserial+"_"+queno+"' onBlur='doOnBlur(this)'>");
                fw1.write("<br>");
                fw1.write("<input type='button' id='btn_mark_"+queserial+"_"+queno+"' onClick=**'insertData(this)'** value='Mark'>");                                   
                fw1.write("<br>");
                if(getmarkentry.equals(""))
                {
                    fw1.write("<input type='button' id='btn_delete' onClick='mark_same()' value='UnMark' disabled='disabled'></td>");                                   
                }
                else
                {
                    fw1.write("<input type='button' id='btn_delete' onClick='mark_same()' value='UnMark'></td>");                                   
                }
                fw1.write("</tr>");
                fw1.write("<tr>");
```

In above code "insertData(this)" is called when clicked on button and I want on that click that ajax is called through jquery. how we achieve this in javascript function.

Comment: It looks to me like it should work as you wrote it. What's the problem?

Comment: That looks more like a servlet than a JSP.

Comment: Try this: var forsplit = $(idvalue).attr("id").split("_");

Comment: problem is that in ajax aftermarksave.jsp is is not called bu when I go through simple ajax call then it run successfully

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this the following:

Put your Ajax script in a function:

```
function functionWithAjaxScript(qtsrl_id){
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: "aftermarksave.jsp",
    data:{setvalues : qtsrl_id},
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) 
    {
        alert("Data passed");
    },
    error: function(data) 
    {
        alert('Not passed Data: '+qtsrl_id);
    }   
});
```

}

trigger the function with `.on()` when your button is clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mybuttonid").on("click",function(){
        functionWithAjaxScript(param);
    });
})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: but #mybuttonid is dynamatically generated in my JSP page ,so how to identify that id

Comment: **2 options:**
_1)_ When generating your DOM attribute you must forsee the attribute with a general class to indentify it, eg: <input type="button" class="aGeneralName"/>. From this point you can use the selector for a class in jquery: $(".aGeneralName")
_2)_ if there is only one button on the page you also can use the selector $('input:[type="submit"]')

Comment: In JSP page there are many buttons and everytime no of buttons created  is not fixed so how we identify that button class or button id

Comment: Ok. So multiple buttons on one page. Where would the `param` value in my code sample `functionWithAjaxScript(param);` come from? Is it encapsulated in the button element as an attribute so the parameter is different in each button? For example: **button 1**: `<input id="button_1" myAttribute="3" />`, **button 2**: `<input id="button_2" myAttribute="9" />`, **button x**: `<input id="button_x" myAttribute="y" />`.

Comment: I've made following example for you [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MeCq8/1/). Assuming that you JSP generates the HTML in such a format or something close to it. If you are able to refactor your JSP so it will generate the `class`-attribute and the `ajaxParam` then this example is usable in your case. _*FYI:*_ I don't JSP, so I don't know what is possible or not :-).

Comment: Ok thanks but in my jsp page button id's are dynamatically created how to pass ajaxParam dynamatically